# JMS Unable to consume messages from Oracle queue using spring/jms

Tags: oracle, spring, queue, jms, oracle-aq

I have followed the spring documentation and setup a Spring JMS listener. Yet, even if I add a message to the queue, my code is not detecting this. My spring config is as follows:

```xml
<bean id="dataSourceListener" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
    <property name="URL" value="xxx"/>
    <property name="user" value="xxx"/>
    <property name="password" value="xxx"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="OracleAqFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceListener" />
</bean>

<jms:listener-container connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory" acknowledge="transacted" concurrency="1-5">
    <jms:listener destination="queuename" ref="myMessageListener"/>
</jms:listener-container>

<bean id="myMessageListener" class="Listener"/>
```

My Java is as follows:

My custom listener:

```java
class Listener implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    void onMessage(Message message) {
        // code to handle message is here
    }
}
```

And my OracleAqFactoryBean:

```java
public class OracleAqFactoryBean implements FactoryBean {
private DataSource dataSource;

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

@Override
public Object getObject() throws Exception {
    return AQjmsFactory.getConnectionFactory( dataSource );
}

@Override
public Class<?> getObjectType() {
    return ConnectionFactory.class;
}

@Override
public boolean isSingleton() {
    return true;
}

}
```

[EDIT: THE ABOVE SETUP IS NOW WORKING SUCCESSFULLY]

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why you are wiring up a `FactoryBean` implementation to the Spring DMLC `destination` property. This is clearly not correct because the [`setDestination`method](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/AbstractMessageListenerContainer.html#setDestination(javax.jms.Destination)) only accepts a `javax.jms.Destination` type. You've wired up the `connectionFactory` and the `messageListener`. That's all that's needed to begin consuming messages. If you remove the `testmq` ref that you have wired to the `destination` property, then messages should be successfully consumed.

Comment: Hi there,Thanks for your reply. I have changed my config and the above setup is now working.

I have tried to port this over into a Grails application though, and it does not consume any messages from the queue. I don't suppose anyone has tried this before and has any ideas?